# Improve speed or find faster alternative to SQL Update

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a 68m rows x 77 columns table (`general_table`) on a MySQL server that contains, amongst other things, `user_id`, `user_name`, `date` and `media_channel`.

There are rare instances (83k of them) where there is a `user_id` but not a `user_name`, we would find that the value for `user_name` is "`-`". I can get this information from the `users_table` table.

To update the values on `general_table` i use the following update function, but given the size of the table it takes a really long time so I'm looking for an alternative.

```
UPDATE 
   general_table as a,
   users_table as b
   SET a.user_name = b.user_name 
   where a.date > '2020-01-01'
   and a.user_id = b.user_id
   and a.media_channel = b.media_channel
   and a.user_name = '-';
```

Answers using Pandas, PyMySQL or SQLAlchemy are also welcome

Keep in mind for those requesting an Explain function that that only works for `SELECT` queries not for updates.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS required the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: hi Strawberry, thank you for the quick input. Issue is that it is work-related so I can't really include much more info than I already have, I'll try creating a similar table and add these.

Comment: Then you've come to the wrong place, my friend.

Comment: just looking for a high-level idea on alternatives or details that can make it faster, hope we can help the working community with obvious restrictions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```sql
UPDATE general_table g
JOIN users_table u ON g.user_id = u.user_id AND g.media_channel = u.media_channel
SET g.user_name = u.user_name 
WHERE g.date > '2020-01-01' AND g.user_name = '-'
```

You want indexes on `general_table(user_name, date, user_id, media_channel)` and on `users_table(user_id, media_channel, user_name)`.

Note:  It will still take some time to update 83k rows, so you might want to do this in batches.